# Import "telegram" could not be resolved (on MacOS)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I try to install pyhon-telegram-bot on macOS.

```
python -i
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

But even though the terminal says that I have successfully installed ptb, I get an import error.

```
Import "telegram" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
```

And also when checking for the installed version, it says no module not found:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named telegram
```

I used the correct command:

```
pip3 install python-telegram-bot
```

I run out of ideas to be honest.
On my Windows PC (at home) all works fine.
I ptb only working on Windows machines?

Comment: ptb works on Mac for sure. I am using it right now.  are you using a virtual environment? from what I can see you're getting python 2.7 error but you installed it using pip3 which means on python 3.

Comment: oh, sorry my bad. I just didnt see that. Thanks mate!